# Selecting text outside of screen

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm having trouble selecting text that's longer than the size of the screen. If I try to increase the selection size downwards, it kinda works for a bit then is spazzes and I can't select anymore. I've only tried this when editing someone else's question as I wanted to format a large chunk of text as code. And if I select from bottom upwards, it's pretty much impossible to go more than half the screen.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I have the same issue, and it makes it impossible to properly format longer pieces of text as code even in multiple steps, since if your selection stops in the middle of a line it just gets cut off.